# Using buttons to manipulate the ctrl key+mousescroll in or out together with jquery: browser window resize/zoom

Tags: jquery, browser, click, window, zooming

OK so if you hold the CTRL button and scroll out on the mouse it will zoom the browser window out and vice versa. How can I tie this action to a click event with jQuery?

```
$('#zoomOut').click(function(){ 
    //Enter Some Code Here
});
$('#zoomIn').click(function(){ 
    //Enter Some Code Here
});
```

It would something like keyDown(); and scroll(); together, I am really not sure...

Thanks DJ.E